# Avoid explicit `default` keyword in Python's dataclass field

Tags: python, api, field, python-dataclasses

[PEP 681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/) introduced dataclass transforms. Among it features, it provides “field specifiers, which describe attributes of individual fields that a static type checker must be aware of, such as whether a default value is provided for the field"

Is there a way to use `default` as a positional argument, instead of a keyword argument?

I would like that this code:

```py
@create_model(init=False)
class CustomerModel:
    id: int = model_field(default=3)
    name: str
```

looks like this:

```py
@create_model(init=False)
class CustomerModel:
    id: int = model_field(3)
    name: str
```

without any complains from the type checkers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [spec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/#field-specifier-parameters) it seems to pretty clearly state:

> This specification formalizes the names and meanings of the parameters
> that must be understood for static type checkers. These standardized
> parameters must be keyword-only.

So I think that means the answer is no.